# Private storage in django

Tags: django

How to store some information in a request storage? I mean the following situation:

There is a variable `v`.

1. Request `r1` is processed: The value of `v` was set: `v = 2` and `v` is "global" and always equal to `2` for `r1`.
2. Request `r2` is processed: The value of `v` was set: `v = 3` and `v` is "global" and always equal to `3` for `r2`.

I know about thread locals. I am looking for any djano-solution or a confirmation that thread locals are good here

Answer (score 1):

All the local variables are destroyed when the request is resolved.

If you want some data to stay persistent across page reloads for specific user, you can store it as a browser cookie, database or use higher level mechanisms - e.g. **session**. If you want to keep separate data for specific anonymous users, session should fit.

These links may be helpful:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/
- https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/06/24/how-django-sessions-work-introduction